# I want access span for hide & show purpose with class name & id name which will start with?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to access a `span` with a specific class and id (the id will start with specific pattern)

```
<span id='asd111' class="demo"></span>
<span id='asd122' class="demo"></span>
<span id='asd133' class="demo"></span>
<span id='asd144' class="demo"></span>
```

Now I want to hide/show above spans using single jQuery statement. How can do this? All span id start with common `asd1` pattern.

Please give me idea as soon as possible.

*i have just given example in this code.. those spans are coming dynamically in my code in different nested divs, so i want hide those with those id pattern & class name???

Comment: It is clear that you haven't even tried to google before coming here. Put in Google 'how to hide an element with jQuery' and I can guarantee there will literally be thousands of results showing you how to do this.

Comment: All the information on how to select and show/hide jQuery elements is available in the documentation: http://api.jquery.com

Comment: look into the code span ids are different & also have specific class name.. i just want to hide such spans?? i tried google but not done??

Comment: Which spans? It's really not clear what your intended goal is here. If you want all of them then just `$('.demo').hide()` works fine

Comment: i have just given example in this code.. those spans are coming dynamically in my code in different nested divs, so i want hide those with those id pattern & class name???

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you to take a look at basic jQuery selectors(https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

If you want to hide the span with specific ID and class name, there is a code that hides span with ID asd111 and class demo:

```
$('#asd111.demo').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of doing this with JQuery.

```js
$('#test').on('click', function(){
  $('span[id^="asd1"].demo').hide();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">Click Me</div>
  
<span id='asd111' class="demo">1</span>
<span id='asd122' class="demo">2</span>
<span id='asd133' class="demo">3</span>
<span id='asd144' class="demo">4</span>
<span id='asd133' class="test">5</span>
<span id='asd144' class="test">6</span>
```

Comment: bro.. i have so many spans starting with such id-pattern but i dont want to hide all.. i just want hide spans with that id-pattern & that class name??

Comment: @webizzdeveloper I've edited code. Is that what you want ?

Answer (score 0):

with jQuery:

```
var asds = $('*[id^="asd"]');

for( var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) { 
  $("asds:eq(" + i  + ")").hide();
}
```